# What does the pipe operator do in SQL?

Tags: sql, bit-manipulation

I am redeveloping an application and have found this sql statement, what does the `|` character do in this part `(au.ExNetBits | 8)`, I haven't seen before and can't find any answer online?

`SELECT au.AccountID,au.ExNetBits FROM AccountUser au (NOLOCK)

WHERE au.CDAGUserId=102  and (au.ExNetBits | 8) = au.ExNetBits`

Comment: What SQL dialect is this? Never seen it before but it's probably a bitwise OR, that would be common in other programming languages. So the query would filter out AccountUser that don't have the 4th bit (=8) set in DB.

Comment: @jods: It's T-SQL, and yea, it's a bitwise OR.

Comment: @Satanicpuppy indeed! I am working with SQL Server every day but never encountered it before. I don't get why you would use a manual bitfield like that rather than simply the `bit` type? Bits in a row are compacted into one byte anyway, aren't they?

Comment: @jods possibly the data came from another system that is using it as a bitfield? One could break it up into columns (may help with readability of queries) but that would also impose the penalty of moving the data back and forth between the two systems would need to have the bit position to column mapping.  I suspect that this is more likely the case than a desire for a compact representation within the database.

Comment: @jods: God knows *why* it'd be done, but it's valid. Could be Sybase, I suppose (which also uses T-SQL except an earlier version). It's not oracle...

Comment: @MichaelT: yeah could be a good reason. Or maybe the code wasn't SQL Server but another DB that lacks the `bit` type. Oracle doesn't have `bit` after all (at least up to 11g), but it doesn't have `|` either. @Satanicpuppy: good bet.

Answer (score 5):

from [the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186714.aspx),

### [| (Bitwise OR) (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186714.aspx)

> Performs a bitwise logical OR operation between two specified integer
> values as translated to binary expressions within Transact-SQL
> statements.
>
> ...
>
> The bitwise | operator performs a bitwise logical OR between the two
> expressions, taking each corresponding bit for both expressions. The
> bits in the result are set to 1 if either or both bits (for the
> current bit being resolved) in the input expressions have a value of
> 1; if neither bit in the input expressions is 1, the bit in the result
> is set to 0.
>
> If the left and right expressions have different integer
> data types (for example, the left *expression* is **smallint** and the right
> *expression* is **int**), the argument of the smaller data type is converted
> to the larger data type. In this example, the **smallint** *expression* is
> converted to an **int**.

for example, see [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db/2),

```
SELECT 1 | 1, 1 | 2, 2 | 4, 3 | 5;
```

outputs

```
1    3    6    7
```

to explain this behavior you must consider the bit patterns of the operands,

### 1 | 1

```
  00000001  = 1
| 00000001  = 1
_______________
  00000001  = 1
```

### 1 | 2

```
  00000001  = 1
| 00000010  = 2
_______________
  00000011  = 3
```

### 2 | 4

```
  00000010  = 2
| 00000100  = 4
_______________
  00000110  = 6
```

### 3 | 5

```
  00000011  = 3
| 00000101  = 5
_______________
  00000111  = 7
```

Answer (score 3):

The `|` (pipe) operator in several dialects of SQL is the [bitwise or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) operator.

In this usage, it is testing to make sure that the value of the column remains the same after applying the bitwise or on it.  Another approach to doing the same thing is to use the bitwise and operator (`&`) to mask just the bits in question and test it against the mask.

I personally find the and to be more idiomatic than the or approach, but thats me.

An SQL Fiddle demonstrating the results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aeb46/4

The contents of the fiddle are:

```
create table foo (bits integer);

insert into foo values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)
```

and

```
select bits from foo where (bits | 2) = bits;
select bits from foo where (bits | 8) = bits;

select bits from foo where (bits & 2) = 2;
select bits from foo where (bits & 8) = 8;
```

The query for the 2 returns 2, 3, 6, 7 while the query for the 8 returns 8, 9.

If you really wanted to, the test for if the 8's bit is set can also be done as:

```
select bits from foo where (bits / 8) % 2 = 1
```

But that's just a bit on the silly side, but it works.

In languages that don't use the C style bitwise operators, there is often a similar function to do the bitwise work.  For example, in Oracle one would use `BITAND` and `BITOR` (see [BITAND](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions014.htm) in the oracle docs for how that would be used) - the `&` in Oracle SQL dialect is the indication of a parameter and a `||` is for string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suspect that the | is a bitwise OR operator. So you're ORing au.ExNetBits with binary 1000 - essentially checking that a single bit is set.

Answer (score 1):

My comment guess was right, a quick Google for Bitwise OR shows that at least MySQL accepts | as a syntax for a bitwise OR:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html

EDIT: as @satanicpuppy points out, it is also valid syntax in SQL Server.