# What does the pipe do in this T-SQL Statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql

What would be the correct way of selecting the content of two columns (Nvarchar) into one single column?

Someone else has achieved this by using:

```
SELECT X.Something | X.SomethingElse AS Post
FROM XTable X WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE This = That
```

It seems as if it takes everything from the column X.Something and from X.SomethingElse and puts everything in one single column (combines the two column into one - NOT concatenation (ie. xxx + yyy = xxxyyy, but rather xxx + yyy = xxx, yyy if that makes sense).

However I'm unable to find any documentation on this syntax, thus I'm thinking of changing it - all examples of how to achieve this (collecting data from two columns in a table and put every single value into one column - each on it's own row).

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037429/what-does-the-pipe-operator-do-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

SELECT (X.Something + X.SomethingElse) AS Post
FROM XTable X WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE This = That

?

Answer (score 0):

The [pipe `|`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186714.aspx) is a bitwise operator in sql server and stands for bitwise or.
The string concatenation operator in sql server is a [plus `+`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx).